# Caching Index with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4jclient

My Neo4j index has over 1.4M entries. My queries are running very slow. I have cached most of the database. However, now I have found that lot of disk read of the lucene index are taking place.

Per [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html) article following code will help witch caching the index.

```
Index<Node> index = graphDb.index().forNodes( "actors" );
((LuceneIndex<Node>) index).setCacheCapacity( "name", 300000 );
```

Anyway I can do it via Neo4jClient? I have got so far as

```
var indexes = _graphClient.GetIndexes(IndexFor.Node);
var index = indexes.ElementAt(0);
```

But then it does not give me an option to set the cache capacity. Any thoughts how I can set the cache parameters via Neo4jClient or reduce the index look up time? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4jClient works via the REST API. The behaviour you are describing is from the native Java API, and not exposed via the REST API. There is no way to do this via Neo4jClient, or any other REST based driver. You may be able to do it via config instead.